# Executing a command with no output

Tags: command-line

How can i execute a command with NO output in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

you can do that in windows using `dir > nul`

but how to do it in UBUNTU?
`

Thanks in advance
***Sorry if I am wrong***

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617182/how-can-i-suppress-all-output-from-a-command-using-bash#617184) answer.

Comment: `ls >/dev/null` will redirect the output to device null.   Microsoft based their DOS on their prior Xenix product (ie. a licensed unix system that IBM wasn't interested in)

Answer (score 2):

Redirect to */dev/null* will silent the result of the command but still display the errors:

```
ls >/dev/null
```

To also hide the errors you can do this:

```
ls >/dev/null 2>&1
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80629/redirect-both-stderr-and-stdout-to-dev-null-with-bin-sh